# How to evaluate messages stored in database using thymeleaf?

Tags: html, spring, thymeleaf

I save a key message along with a string in my bbdd this way:

```
#{message.format.error} + 'foo string'
```

In my view, I retrieve the list of errors like this:

```
<p th:each="error : ${errors}">
  <span th:utext="${error.message}"></span>
</p>
```

But I get the bbdd content in the html span:

```
<span>#{message.format.error} + 'foo string'</span>
```

How I can evaluate this?

If I put my bbdd content in a span directly, it will work:

```
<span th:utext="#{message.format.error} + 'foo string'"></span>
```

The resulting HTML is:

```
<span>Error foo: foo string</span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [pre-process](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#preprocessing) your expression before hand. See the code below

```
<p th:each="error : ${errors}">
  <span th:utext="__${error.message}__"></span>
</p>
```